# RTP packet to image

Tags: c#, rtp

Получаю rtp пакет с камеры
[image: Лог моей программы]

[image: Wireshark]

как эти пакеты конвертировать в изображение а лучше MemoryStream(ImageStream)? 
Формат потока от камеры h264